# spring boot integration test: Autowired members have null members

Tags: spring-boot, integration-testing, spock

I have the following spock integrtaion test for my spring-data-rest webapp built using spring boot 1.5.2.RELEASE.

```
    @SpringBootTest(classes = com.my.server.Application.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT) 
class MyWebAppSpec extends Specification {    

    @Autowired
    DemoData demoData;

    def setup() {
        createDemoData();
    }     

    private void createDemoData() {
        if (demoData.myMap.keySet().size() == 0) {
            demoData.load();
        }        
    }
...
}
```

The DemoData class looks like this:

```
@Component
public class DemoData {

    public Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<>();

    public void load() {...}
...
}
```

What I am finding is that in the createDemoData method of MyWebAppSpec demoData.myMap is null rather than an empty Map. Why is this so when I initialize it as an empty map in the DemoData class and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I do not fully understand why I am seeing the DemoData member myMap to be null but I have determined a fix to the problem.

The fix is to make the DemoData member myMap protected / private and add an accessor method to access it. This fixes the problem. I am guessing that this may be due to spring using CGLIB proxies and how pointcuts are defined. Perhaps its a bug in spring that could be fixed?

With the workaround my test code looks as follows:

```
    @SpringBootTest(classes = com.my.server.Application.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT) 
class MyWebAppSpec extends Specification {    

    @Autowired
    DemoData demoData;

    def setup() {
        createDemoData();
    }     

    private void createDemoData() {
        if (demoData.getMyMap().keySet().size() == 0) { //NOTE accessor method used here
            demoData.load();
        }        
    }
...
}
```

and my DemoData class looks like this:

```
@Component
public class DemoData {

    protected Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<>(); //NOTE: member is protected now

    public Map<String, String> getMyMap() { //NOTE: Accessor method added here
        return myMap;
    }


    public void load() {...}
..
```

.
    }